# My Smooth brush ruins my mesh

Tags: sculpting

I am very new to Blender and started a tutorial.

I am using the smooth brush to smoothen out the letters of my 3d mesh, but instead of smoothing it out it completely ruins the mesh and kind of turns it 2d.

[image]
[image]

This is how its supposed to look: (the letters become more smooth and liquid like)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the community. Can you give an screen shot of what the correct output is supposed to like?

Comment: hi and thank you @jwrush , I included what it's supposed to look like

Comment: Try enabling "dynotopo" on the sidebar.  Is that more what you're after?